# Waiting for File Lock to Be Released

Tags: java, io, fileutils

There are some Java questions similar to this one but none of them had accepted answers that I could find and my situation is a little more specific.  I have a program that processes files one at a time as they are fed into a directory.  At times, the files may remain locked in use by the program dropping them off for a few seconds after they've are visible to my program.  I have no control over that program.  In my program I already have error handling to recover if a file is in use when my program tries to read it.  It results in the file being skipped entirely.  What I want to implement is a retry scheme to see if the file becomes unlocked after a few seconds.  In another question here I found a suggestion to use `FileUtils.touch()`.  This is convenient because I'm already using FileUtils in my project.  According to the javadoc, `FileUtils.touch()` with throw an `IOException` if the file is in use by another process.  Sounds great.  However, one of the comments under the answer I mentioned warned of a race condition without any explanation.  Here is the code I'm considering implementing:

```
// Implementing Sason's suggestion
int retries = 0;
while (retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
    try {
        processFile(file);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // Assumes this is a file in use exception... bad thing?
        log.warn("File is in use.  Waiting 1 second to retry.");
        retries++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            log.warn("Thread interrupted while waiting for file lock to clear.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I realize that the file could become locked again between the FileUtils.touch() and the `processFile()` method call (and I presume that is the race condition warned about in the unaccepted answer I found) but that's fine.  The `processFile()` method will just handle the lock error like it currently does.  To be clear, in this case it's perfectly OK for the file to be open by another process but it cannot be locked.

Also, while sometimes the file does become unlocked after a second or two, in some instances the program dropping off the files keeps the lock indefinitely.  I also need to avoid infinitely trying to reprocess the same file as well as be able to notify the sender when a file could not be processed after the retries have been exhausted.

So am I missing something here?  Is there a better/safer way to do this?

Comment: It doesn't sound like `touch()` is a reliable way to test whether the file is open. It might work on a particular system with a particular process writing the file, and that's fine, but if you run the code elsewhere or change the writer, you'll need to re-test to make sure it still works. The right way to do this is with a `FileLock`, but that requires the writing program to use the underlying file system lock mechanism.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question.  It's ok if the file is open in another process that doesn't have the file locked (like, for instance, NotePad++).  It just can't be locked because `processFile()` will attempt to lock the file.  I do see your point about `FileLock` but you're right in that it would require quite a bit of refactoring.  I do think `touch()` will work cross platform with the same caveat that another program might have the file open but not locked.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a SchedueledExecutorService to submit work with some delay that tries to process the file. If the  processing fails, post the work again and again until it succeeds.

Is FileUtils.touch necessary here? Why not just try to read the file and if it fails retry?

The thread.sleep thing is kind of ugly. If processing several files, each one has to use a it's own thread until it is done. A SchedueledExecutorService would be more efficient.

Comment: I agree. The race is because there's no atomicity between the check and the action. If the action fails because it can't acquire a lock, no problem. Just try later.

Comment: That's an interesting idea that I had considered and initially rejected because sometimes the file will remain locked indefinitely and the program would be stuck looping on a file that cannot be processed.  In the error handling a notification is provided to the sender that the file is unable to be processed and the file is added to an ignore list.  At the end of the day a list of files that could not be processed is sent to the sender.  I don't really want to change that behavior I just want to allow a few seconds for the file to become available before ending up on the unprocessed list.

Comment: Also, I agree the Thread.sleep() thing is kind of ugly but the files do need to be handled synchronously anyway so it's OK if it's blocking the next file to be processed.  I almost wish that I didn't have to process the files sequentially (as close to arrival order as possible).  That would actually simplify things quite a bit because I could do exactly what you said and have the runnable itself expire after a certain number of retries.  I could even use Future<T> instead.

Comment: Well the Executor doesn't stop you from keeping count of retries and stop retrying. Another thing is you are ignoring the interrupted exception and continuing looping. You compromise the applications ability to shutdown timely.

Comment: You're right about the InterruptedException, thanks for pointing that out.  I guess I'm missing something on the Executor though.  It's too long for a comment but if I'm processing 10 files at once and the first one is locked, the runnable would need to retry on that file internally or track that file internally so that the next time it executed it would know it was trying for the second, third, etc., time.  That seems like it would be more confusing.  Is that really any better than what I've done?  I must be missing something.

Comment: Does the current file have to be processed or put on fail list before the next file can begin processing? Why not just keep the current solution, remove the touch call and put processFile there instead and let processFile throw IOException? Wouldn't that solve it?

Comment: Yes.  Now that's an interesting idea.  I could get rid of the `FileUtils.touch()` call and the boolean but I would still need a retry counter and the sleep().  That does clean it up some. :)

Comment: Actually... I spoke to soon.  I lose the error handling because processFile() doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: :) Can't you just make sure it does? How does processFile look? Somewhere it must try to read the file where an IOException can be thrown.  Does processFile consume the exception? If so, make it so it doesn't.